# Menu items doesn't show nor in toolbar neither in overflow

Tags: android, menuitem

I want to have a toolbar for my app which has two icons, one for Settings at the end left of toolbar (when clicked SettingsActivity starts) and another for user profile at the end right of it. I'm using the below code, but unfortunately none of icons are shown in toolbar or overflow section. Any suggestion is appreciated.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        toolbar = UiUtils.findView(this, R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);

        // Remove application name from toolbar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_action_bar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**main_Action_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:xmls="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Settings"
    android:visible="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_settings_action_bar" />

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_profile"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Profile"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_profile_action_bar" />
</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
</style
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` to your `onCreate` and

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_Action_bar, menu);

    return true; 
}
```

Comment: android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity doesn't have setHasOptionsMenu()

Answer (score 1):

Should also override `Activity`'s [`onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu)):

```
protected boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_Action_bar, menu);
    return true;
}
```

To react on menu clicks override: [`onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)).

Comment: I definitely write those 2 methods but i don't write them in the question for shortness

Answer (score 0):

After some investigating i found that i should edit the **menu_action_bar.xml**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
.
.
</menu
```